# shopware watch problem. I can't run this command ./bin/watch-administration.sh

Tags: shopware

User
When I want to run this command ./bin/watch-administration.sh i get this error

```
Child
    Time: 5165ms
    Entrypoint storefront = css/storefront.css js/storefront.js
       78 modules
Child
    Time: 3688ms
    Entrypoint gt-arktis01 = css/gt-arktis01.css js/gt-arktis01.js
       498 modules
Child
    Time: 3587ms
    Entrypoint gt-kamasha01 = css/gt-kamasha01.css js/gt-kamasha01.js
       63 modules
ℹ ｢wdm｣: Compiled with warnings.
ERROR in src/app/mixin/placeholder.mixin.ts:16:34
TS2694: Namespace 'EntitySchema' has no exported member 'Entity'.
    14 |     methods: {
    15 |         placeholder<EntityName extends keyof EntitySchema.Entities>(
  > 16 |             entity: EntitySchema.Entity<EntityName>,
       |                                  ^^^^^^
    17 |             field: keyof EntitySchema.Entity<EntityName>,
    18 |             fallbackSnippet: string,
    19 |         ) {

ERROR in src/app/mixin/placeholder.mixin.ts:17:39
TS2694: Namespace 'EntitySchema' has no exported member 'Entity'.
    15 |         placeholder<EntityName extends keyof EntitySchema.Entities>(
    16 |             entity: EntitySchema.Entity<EntityName>,
  > 17 |             field: keyof EntitySchema.Entity<EntityName>,
       |                                       ^^^^^^
    18 |             fallbackSnippet: string,
    19 |         ) {
    20 |             if (!entity) {

ERROR in src/app/mixin/placeholder.mixin.ts:24:13
TS2578: Unused '@ts-expect-error' directive.
    22 |             }
    23 |
  > 24 |             // @ts-expect-error - we know it is a string because we check it beforehand
       |             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    25 |             if (Shopware.Utils.types.isString(entity[field]) && entity[field].length > 0) {
    26 |                 return entity[field];
    27 |             }

ERROR in src/app/mixin/placeholder.mixin.ts:32:13
TS2578: Unused '@ts-expect-error' directive.
    30 |             // Return the field from parent translation if set
    31 |             const parentLanguageId = Shopware.Context.api.language ? Shopware.Context.api.language.parentId : null;
  > 32 |             // @ts-expect-error - we just check if translations exists
       |             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    33 |             if (parentLanguageId && parentLanguageId.length > 0 && entity.translations) {
    34 |                 // @ts-expect-error - we had checked if translations exists
    35 |                 const translation = (entity.translations as unknown as {

ERROR in src/app/mixin/placeholder.mixin.ts:34:17
TS2578: Unused '@ts-expect-error' directive.
    32 |             // @ts-expect-error - we just check if translations exists
    33 |             if (parentLanguageId && parentLanguageId.length > 0 && entity.translations) {
  > 34 |                 // @ts-expect-error - we had checked if translations exists
       |                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    35 |                 const translation = (entity.translations as unknown as {
    36 |                     [key: string]: string,
    37 |                 }[]).find((entry) => {

ERROR in src/app/mixin/placeholder.mixin.ts:49:13
TS2578: Unused '@ts-expect-error' directive.
    47 |             }
    48 |
  > 49 |             // @ts-expect-error - we check if the field exists
       |             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    50 |             // Return the field from translated if set
    51 |             // eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-unsafe-call
    52 |             if (entity.translated != null && entity.translated.hasOwnProperty(field)) {

ERROR in src/app/mixin/placeholder.mixin.ts:53:17
TS2578: Unused '@ts-expect-error' directive.
    51 |             // eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-unsafe-call
    52 |             if (entity.translated != null && entity.translated.hasOwnProperty(field)) {
  > 53 |                 // @ts-expect-error - we check if the field exists beforehand
       |                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    54 |                 if (entity.translated[field] !== null) {
    55 |                     // @ts-expect-error - we check if the field exists beforehand
    56 |                     // eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-unsafe-return

ERROR in src/app/mixin/placeholder.mixin.ts:55:21
TS2578: Unused '@ts-expect-error' directive.
    53 |                 // @ts-expect-error - we check if the field exists beforehand
    54 |                 if (entity.translated[field] !== null) {
  > 55 |                     // @ts-expect-error - we check if the field exists beforehand
       |                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    56 |                     // eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-unsafe-return
    57 |                     return entity.translated[field];
    58 |                 }

ERROR in src/core/data/entity-definition.data.ts:37:35
TS2694: Namespace 'EntitySchema' has no exported member 'Entity'.
    35 | // eslint-disable-next-line sw-deprecation-rules/private-feature-declarations
    36 | export default class EntityDefinition<EntityName extends keyof EntitySchema.Entities> {
  > 37 |     readonly entity: EntitySchema.Entity<EntityName>;
       |                                   ^^^^^^
    38 |
    39 |     readonly properties: Properties;
    40 |

ERROR in src/core/data/entity-definition.data.ts:41:64
TS2694: Namespace 'EntitySchema' has no exported member 'Entity'.
    39 |     readonly properties: Properties;
    40 |
  > 41 |     constructor({ entity, properties }: { entity: EntitySchema.Entity<EntityName>, properties: Properties }) {
       |                                                                ^^^^^^
    42 |         this.entity = entity;
    43 |         this.properties = properties;
    44 |     }

ERROR in src/module/sw-custom-entity/component/sw-generic-cms-page-assignment/index.ts:144:40
TS7006: Parameter 'section' implicitly has an 'any' type.
    142 |             }
    143 |
  > 144 |             cmsPage.sections?.forEach((section) => {
        |                                        ^^^^^^^
    145 |                 section.blocks?.forEach((block) => {
    146 |                     block.slots?.forEach((slot) => {
    147 |                         const slotOverride = this.slotOverrides[slot.id];

ERROR in src/module/sw-custom-entity/component/sw-generic-cms-page-assignment/index.ts:145:42
TS7006: Parameter 'block' implicitly has an 'any' type.
    143 |
    144 |             cmsPage.sections?.forEach((section) => {
  > 145 |                 section.blocks?.forEach((block) => {
        |                                          ^^^^^
    146 |                     block.slots?.forEach((slot) => {
    147 |                         const slotOverride = this.slotOverrides[slot.id];
    148 |                         if (!slotOverride) {

ERROR in src/module/sw-custom-entity/component/sw-generic-cms-page-assignment/index.ts:146:43
TS7006: Parameter 'slot' implicitly has an 'any' type.
    144 |             cmsPage.sections?.forEach((section) => {
    145 |                 section.blocks?.forEach((block) => {
  > 146 |                     block.slots?.forEach((slot) => {
        |                                           ^^^^
    147 |                         const slotOverride = this.slotOverrides[slot.id];
    148 |                         if (!slotOverride) {
    149 |                             return;

ERROR in src/module/sw-custom-entity/component/sw-generic-cms-page-assignment/index.ts:189:41
TS7006: Parameter 'block' implicitly has an 'any' type.
    187 |                 }
    188 |
  > 189 |                 section.blocks.forEach((block) => {
        |                                         ^^^^^
    190 |                     if (!block.slots) {
    191 |                         return;
    192 |                     }

ERROR in src/module/sw-custom-entity/component/sw-generic-cms-page-assignment/index.ts:194:42
TS7006: Parameter 'slot' implicitly has an 'any' type.
    192 |                     }
    193 |
  > 194 |                     block.slots.forEach((slot) => {
        |                                          ^^^^
    195 |                         if (!slot.config) {
    196 |                             return;
    197 |                         }

ERROR in src/module/sw-custom-entity/component/sw-generic-cms-page-assignment/index.ts:243:49
TS7006: Parameter 'block' implicitly has an 'any' type.
    241 |                 changes.sections.forEach((section) => {
    242 |                     if (Array.isArray(section.blocks)) {
  > 243 |                         section.blocks.forEach((block) => {
        |                                                 ^^^^^
    244 |                             if (Array.isArray(block.slots)) {
    245 |                                 block.slots.forEach((slot) => {
    246 |                                     slotOverrides[slot.id] = slot.config;

ERROR in src/module/sw-custom-entity/component/sw-generic-cms-page-assignment/index.ts:245:54
TS7006: Parameter 'slot' implicitly has an 'any' type.
    243 |                         section.blocks.forEach((block) => {
    244 |                             if (Array.isArray(block.slots)) {
  > 245 |                                 block.slots.forEach((slot) => {
        |                                                      ^^^^
    246 |                                     slotOverrides[slot.id] = slot.config;
    247 |                                 });
    248 |                             }

ERROR in src/module/sw-order/component/sw-order-state-history-modal/index.ts:84:57
TS7006: Parameter 'transaction' implicitly has an 'any' type.
    82 |             const entityIds = [
    83 |                 this.order.id,
  > 84 |                 ...(this.order.transactions ?? []).map((transaction) => {
       |                                                         ^^^^^^^^^^^
    85 |                     return transaction.id;
    86 |                 }),
    87 |                 ...(this.order.deliveries ?? []).map((delivery) => {

ERROR in src/module/sw-order/component/sw-order-state-history-modal/index.ts:87:55
TS7006: Parameter 'delivery' implicitly has an 'any' type.
    85 |                     return transaction.id;
    86 |                 }),
  > 87 |                 ...(this.order.deliveries ?? []).map((delivery) => {
       |                                                       ^^^^^^^^
    88 |                     return delivery.id;
    89 |                 }),
    90 |             ];

ERROR in src/module/sw-order/component/sw-order-state-history-modal/index.ts:182:17
TS2578: Unused '@ts-expect-error' directive.
    180 |
    181 |             if (this.page === 1) {
  > 182 |                 // @ts-expect-error - states exists
        |                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    183 |                 // Prepend start state
    184 |                 entries.push(this.createEntry(states, this.order));
    185 |             }

ERROR in src/module/sw-order/component/sw-order-state-history-modal/index.ts:190:17
TS2578: Unused '@ts-expect-error' directive.
    188 |                 // @ts-expect-error - the entityName have to be order, order_transaction or order_delivery
    189 |                 states[entry.entityName] = entry.toStateMachineState;
  > 190 |                 // @ts-expect-error - states exists
        |                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    191 |                 entries.push(this.createEntry(states, entry));
    192 |             });
    193 |

ERROR in src/module/sw-settings-country/component/sw-settings-country-address-handling/index.ts:327:13
TS2578: Unused '@ts-expect-error' directive.
    325 |             this.customer = customer;
    326 |
  > 327 |             // @ts-expect-error - value exists
        |             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    328 |             void this.renderFormattingAddress(this.customer.defaultBillingAddress);
    329 |         },
```

I tried to install the plugins a gain and shut down the docker